# What would be the translation of "non-elf" in Elvish?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, tolkien-languages

I'm thinking of something like "alien" or "gentile", that doesn't sound/read as clunky as "non-elf".

Comment: Welcome, I'm not quite clear on what you're asking? Did he have elvish translations of the word Man, Dwarf, Orc etc..?

Comment: @Edlothiad I think the OP is looking for a word that literally means "non-elf", i.e. covers *all* of those possibilities you mention.

Comment: Hmm, that is quite interesting

Comment: I don't think so, but it would probably be Úmeldar.

Comment: Indeed, I am looking for a word like "outsider", or whatever would be appropritate. So, if "eldar" is the word for elves / elfkind, is "Úm-" the prefix for "not"?

Comment: It's more like "not to be" or "not to do", like _Úmanyar_, not of Aman.

Comment: @isanae looking forward for another epic answer!

Comment: @Gallifreyan I'm not much of a language expert. Jason is much better, I'm hoping he passes by.

Comment: A from-principle derivation will do, but I was hoping for a word that had been used (either by JRR or someone writing in a universe which borrows his language.) Sorry that wasn't clear.

Comment: Like I said, I don't think Tolkien ever used a single word to describe non-elves. You have stuff like _fírima_ ("mortal"), _engwar_ ("sickly"), _apanónar_ ("after-born"), but those only apply to Men, not the other races in general.

Comment: Hmm. I need to look up the origins of the dwarves - I would have thought "after-born" would describe all of them. Thanks!

Comment: @tehwalrus Don't forget to [use _@username_ to ping someone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/300549) if you want them to get a notification that you replied to their comment. And welcome to stackexchange! :)

Comment: The After-comers would have described Men (including Hobbits), Dwarves, and possibly Orcs. Ents, less sure. But in practice it seems only to have been used for Men.

Comment: @isanae "Úmeldar" could conceivably refer to Avari as well. Perhaps _Úquendi_ (bear with me; I'm not sure how the prefix works when the stem begins with a consonant)?

Comment: @Spencer Did you check my answer below?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There is none**.

The relevant text is the essay *Quendi and Eldar*, published in History of Middle-earth 11: *The War of the Jewels*.

This is a lengthy essay, with appendices, covering:

> Origin and Meanings of the Elvish words referring to Elves and their varieties. With Appendices on their names for other Incarnates.

It also provides a good deal of history as interesting asides.

Section B, "Meanings and use of the various terms applied to the Elves and their varieties in Quenya, Telerin, and Sindarin", contains the following two statements:

> Moerbin was similarly an equivalent for Avari; but that it did not mean only 'Dark-elves' is seen by its ready application to other Incarnates when they later became known. By the Sindar anyone dwelling outside Beleriand, or entering their realm from outside, was called a Morben.

And:

> The Men of the Three Houses were also soon removed from the class of Moerbin. (Note 8, p. 408) They were given their own name, Edain, and were seldom actually called Celbin, but they were recognized as belonging to this class, which became practically equivalent to 'peoples in alliance in the War against Morgoth'.

These are the only two terms given, which are explictly stated to be Sindarin, and as we can see they include Elves as well as other Incarnates.

Other notes in this essay cover Quenya and Telerin, noting that whereas '*quen*' was a general word meaning 'person' and was used in compounds for other Incarnates too (examples of '*roquen*, horsemen', '*kiryaquen*, sailor' and '*arquen*, noble' are given), '*Quende*, *Quendi*' was exclusively used for Elves.

In contrast to Sindarin:

> Moriquendi was now applied to all other Elves, except the Noldor and Sindar, that is to Avari or to any kind of Elves that at the time of the coming of the Noldor had not long dwelt in Beleriand and were not subjects of Elwe. It was never applied, however, to any but Elvish peoples.

The essay also contains three appendices which are relevant to this question:

- Appendix A. Elvish names for Men.
- Appendix B. Elvish names for the Dwarves.
- Appendix C. Elvish names for the Orcs.

While these appendices cover much additional interesting material, providing confirmation of a general term for all Men ("Firyar 'Mortals', or Firimar"), giving the Quenya "Attalyar", Sindarin "Tad-dail" term for "Bipeds" (from context clearly a term for unintelligent two-legged beasts), no overall term for non-Elves is given.

Comment: Aren't you [this user](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/74177/victim-of-circumstance)? See [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for merging accounts.

Comment: Also [this user](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/72342/victim-of-circumstance). You should really keep tabs on this stuff :)

Answer (score 3):

Although there are a variety of euphemisms applied to individual races by the Elves, I've never come across a word for "all non-elvish people" and, as far as I can tell, Tolkien never used one. We can make one up though, in one of the various Elvish languages. I chose Quendi, because it's the one I know best.

#### *Úquendi*

This uses the negative prefix *ú-* ("not-, un-, in-") and *quendi* ("speakers", the name Elves use to refer to themselves). It literally means "not-Elf" or "un-Elf". I'm not sure whether the Quendi would use such a word or come up with something more poetic (like they usually do).

As an aside, the *ú-* prefix has a complicated history. Tolkien wasn't sure if it should represent simple negation (as above) or something bad, evil or immoral, such as for the *Úmaiar*, the Maiar who followed Melkor, like the Balrogs. He seems to have settled on *ú-* being a negative particle in the end.

#### Correction on *Úmeldar*

I proposed *Úmeldar* in my comment above, but I'm not sure of its correctness anymore. Since a discussion followed the comment, I won't remove it, but I'll give more information here.

*Eldar* ("people of the stars") is mostly used to refer to the Elves who accepted to leave Cuiviénen with Oromë (contrast with *Avari*, those who didn't). *Quendi* is the correct word to refer to all the elves.

I also think it should be *Úeldar*, as *úm-* seems to be a verb prefix. I mentioned *Úmanyar* as another example of the *úm-* prefix, but it is in fact a contraction of *Úamanyar*. This word is composed of four parts:

- *ú-*, a negative prefix, like *not-*, *un-* or *in-* in English;
- *aman*, "blessed, free from evil", but also used as the name of "the Blessed Realm", where the Valar live;
- *-ya*, an adjectival ending (a way to turn a noun into an adjective); and
- *r*, a plural ending.

So *Úeldar* would literally be "those who are not people of the stars", which would not be an answer to the original question. It's also a made-up word, by the way: *Avari* ("recusant, one who refuses to act as advised or commanded") is used by the Eldar instead.

Comment: "Tolkien never used a single word for "all non-elvish people"" What's the source for this statement?

Comment: @gef05 I've reworded it to make it clearer that it was as far as I know. Thanks.

Comment: @isanae I have accepted the answer by Victim of Circumstance, since it better reflects what I intend to use the answer for. Both your answers seem worthy of being marked correct, but I had to get a cigarette paper between them somehow. Thank you, and for your help in the comments last night too.

Answer (score 2):

The Quenya word ***fírima*** means "mortal" or "those able to die."  According to the [Tolkien Gateway](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Mortals):

> Mortals were any of the races of Arda who were subject to old age and death (as for example Hobbits), but applied especially to the race of Men.

The plural (the way to designate an entire race or collection of races) would therefore be ***fírimar.***

This word is used mostly for Men, though it could be for other mortals.

Comment: Which were the races which weren't "subject to old age and death"? For example, dwarves? I am not very familiar with the creation story (the Silmarillion etc).

Comment: @tehwalrus Ainur (and maybe other spiritual beings) weren't. This includes Balrogs, dragons, ents etc. so I wouldn't equalise mortal with non-elf.

Comment: Note that _fírima_, as a euphemism applied to a mortal race, was used _exclusively_ for Men: "A general term for Men of all kinds and races, as
distinct from Elves, was only devised after their mortality and brief life-span became known to the Elves by experience. They were then called _Firyar_ 'Mortals', or _Fírima_ of similar sense (literally 'those apt to die'). [...] These words were derived from the stem *PHIRI 'exhale, expire, breathe out', which had no original connexion with death." (HoME 11, "Appendix A. Elvish names for Men") Although interesting, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Mithoron Neither Dragons nor Ents are Ainur.

Comment: @isanae Well I added "other" for guys who need Tolkien to tell them everything in blatant way to be sure. Ents had "spirits summoned from afar" by Yavanna and dragons, Carharoth, maybe others, had evil spirits.